# Can't import python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple error with the import 
But how to solve it?;))
I'm noob and it is testing task

One of the conditions is to separate the parent class from the child!
That is, everything good with their location [classes_1.py, classes_2.py]

Main:

```
n10_12.py

from classes_1 import User
from classes_2 import Privileges, Admin

admin_33 = Admin('mike', 'logsdale', 'africa', 'customer')

admin_33.privilege.show_privileges()
admin_33.descibe_user()
```

Classes two file:

1)

```
classes_1.py

class User():

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location='', field=''):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.location = location
        self.field = field
        self.full_name = self.first_name.title() + ' ' + self.last_name.title()
        self.login_attemts = 0

    def descibe_user(self):

        print('\nFull name: ' + self.full_name + 
            '\nLocation: ' + self.location.title() + 
            '\nField: ' + self.field.title() + '\n'
            )

    def greet_user(self):
        print('Hello, ' + self.full_name)

    def read_login_attemts(self):
        print('In this time login attempts are ' + str(self.login_attemts))

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attemts += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        self.login_attemts = 0
```

2)

```
classes_2.py

class Privileges():
    def __init__(self):
        self.privileges = [
                    'access to add msg',
                    'access to delete users',
                    'access to ban users',
                     ]


    def show_privileges(self):
        print('Hi Admin, your privileges is: ')
        for kk in self.privileges:
            print('\n- ' + kk.lower())




class Admin(User):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location='', field=''):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, location, field)
        self.privilege = Privileges()
```

Traceback:

python n10_12.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "n10_12.py", line 2, in 
    from classes_2 import Privileges, Admin

File ..\classes_2.py", line 28, in 
    class Admin(User):

NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: The error is clear, `User` is undefined in your second .py file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import User in classes_2.py :

```
from classes_1 import User

class Privileges():
    def __init__(self):
        self.privileges = [
                    'access to add msg',
                    'access to delete users',
                    'access to ban users',
                     ]


    def show_privileges(self):
        print('Hi Admin, your privileges is: ')
        for kk in self.privileges:
            print('\n- ' + kk.lower())  

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, location='', field=''):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, location, field)
        self.privilege = Privileges()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify conditions..  (One of the conditions is to separate the parent class from the child! That is, everything good with their location [classes_1.py, classes_2.py])

Comment: @Izzumi ok, you need to import it then. You should know, btw, that this isn't a common pattern in Python, that is, all classes in separate files.

Comment: @Izzumi Not sure to understand. Aren't they already separated ? (Admin is in classes_2, User in classes_1 ?). Or do you mean that you want to specify later which class Admin inherits ? (in n10_12.py)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks I got it ;)